# Do attack bonuses from different feats stack?

Tags: dnd-4e

Like the +1 bonus from Implement Expertise and the +1 from Versatile Expertise?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NO, they do no stack**

Typed bonuses do not stack with same typed bonuses. In your example the feats do not stack.

However, some feats provide untyped bonuses.

For instance the Fighter Feat `Fighter Weapon Specialization` provides an untyped +1 to damage. This will stack with the feat bonus to damage from a focus feat (`Heavy Blade Focus`, `Light Blade Focus` etc).

Answer (score 4):

Bonuses of the same type do not stack. In this case, both are listed as `Feat` bonuses, so they do not stack.