# Does White Lotus Dueling Expertise apply to basic melee attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, bard

I have a Skald (bard) that just hit level 2. I wanted to pick up White Lotus Dueling Expertise, but when I add it in the character builder, I don't see a change in my my melee basic attack accuracy.

The text says:

> You gain a +1 feat bonus to the attack rolls of arcane powers and basic attacks that you make with any weapon or implement with which you have proficiency. This bonus increases to +2 at 11th level and +3 at 21st level.
>
> You also gain proficiency with orbs, rods, staffs, or wands.

I am proficient with longswords, have 20 CHA (+5), and have Battle Song Expertise (which grants +1), so my current MBA attack bonus is +10 (1/2 level + 5 Ability + 3 Prof + 1 Feat). When I add White Lotus Dueling Expertise, I expected that to go up to +11.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bonuses to attack provided by Battle Song Expertise and White Lotus Dueling Expertise both are of the **feat** type of bonus. [Multiple bonuses of the **feat** type do not stack.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9510/4563) In fact, in general, multiple bonuses of any single type don’t stack.

Comment: Whelp. That explains it. So, if I can only get one modifier from a feat, what is the best "bang for your buck"? I'm trying to optimize accuracy...

Comment: @convoke That’s a separate question, and not one I’m qualified to answer unfortunately. Feel free to ask that question separately, though. You will most likely need to give more detail about your current build and your overall goals, however.

Comment: Also, a minor correction- a bonus isn't necessarily a "feat bonus" because it comes from a feat, or a "power bonus" because it comes from a power, etc.  If it says "feat bonus" (as in this case), it's a feat bonus.  If it just says "bonus" with no modifier beforehand, it's untyped, and it would stack.

Comment: @convoke I believe JLan’s comment was for you, and he is correct. Feats usually give feat-type bonuses, but they don’t *have* to and you may be able to find some that work for you that don’t.